# Sharepoint Excel Dynamic dashboard according to a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-services, dashboard-designer-2013, dashboard

I've a list which has something like this:
List Title  Status
Title 1     Active
Title 2     Pending
Title 3     Active
Title 4     Closed

I need an Excel BI dashboard which should be dynamically changed according to the above list. 
I should a PI chart which should display percentage of Active users, percentage of pending users etc.

Can someone tell me how could i achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to query SharePoint Data with Excel, you should use PowerQuery. Beware, if your sharepoint site hasn't been created with the english language template, you'll have to query the list through ODATA

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.  I need to have a sharepoint dashboard which dashboard should be dynamically changed according to the list i have.. Is that possible with PowerQuery? Thanks a lot

Comment: I used PowerQuery, I can refresh data inside the excel file, but i can not refresh data in sharepoint Online.. any idea?

Comment: Not sure to understand the error you are facing. What do you mean by "refreshing data in sharePoint online" ? Updating list elements from values edited in your Excel file ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I need my excel file to be updating when we change Sharepoint list values!!

Comment: For automatic update of your query, you may apply the  following walkthrough : http://www.excel2013.info/power-query/automatic-update/